# System performance analysis

Tags: cpu

I am trying to understand how performance can be measured using the time command in Unix systems.  Lets say I run the time command for three different machines and get the following results:

A: 282u(user cpu time) 3S(system cpu time) 4:45(elapsed time) 99%

B: 238u 5S 4:13 98%

C: 302u 9S 5.11 97%

Which system will have the highest performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) tells, user time is how long your program spent on CPU and System time is time spent in kernel performing privilege operations such as I/O calls `read`, `write` behalf of your program. Therefore `User + System` time in case of machine `A` is smaller compared to other machines, resulting best performance out of all three machines.

Elapsed time is the time measured by wall clock i.e time measured from process spawned and it terminates. Though it is nothing to do with CPU usage.